# Trying to capitalize abbreviated day of the week in NSDateFormatter object in iOS

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am working on an application in iOS where I have an NSDateFormatter object as follows:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM. dd"];
 NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
 NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
```

My output is: Tue, Dec. 10 and I would like to display: TUE, Dec. 10 instead.

My problem though is that the day of the week has only the first letter capitalized, and not the entire day (i.e.  I am getting "Tue", and I would like to display "TUE").  The formatting of the month is fine (i.e. "Dec" I am happy with).

I have checked the specs on date formatting and unfortunately there is no conventional way of doing this using the NSDateFormatter class.  Is there a way around this to still capitalize all of the abbreviated letters in the day of the week only without touching the month?

Comment: Maybe you should just do setShortWeekdaySymbols on your NSDateFormatter?  `[dateFormat setShortWeekdaySymbols:@[@"SUN",@"MON",...]];`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to do this directly with the date formatter. The easiest would be to process the string after formatting the date.

```
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[dateString substringToIndex:3] uppercaseString], [dateString substringFromIndex:3]];
```

Update:

The above assumes that `EEE` always gives a 3-letter weekday abbreviation. It may be possible that there is some locale or language where this assumption isn't valid. A better solution would then be the following:

```
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
NSRange commaRange = [dateString rangeOfString:@","];
dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[dateString substringToIndex:commaRange.location] uppercaseString], [dateString substringFromIndex:commaRange.location]];
```

Comment: @SamBudda It won't be. The format is `EEE` which always gives a three-letter weekday. So `Thursday` becomes `Thu`.

Comment: @rmaddy That's contrary to this documentation linked to from Apples Date Formatter docs: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns - It gives 4 letter examples for EEE, e.g.: week day: E - 1..3 - Tues

Comment: @Jasarien I see what you are talking about but in real life when I use `EEE` I always get a 3-letter weekday abbreviation. I've never seen `EEE` give a 4-letter result.

Comment: Does it return localised names? Is it possible for a localised name to be more than 3?

Comment: @Jasarien Now that's a good question. I suppose there is a locale out there where `EEE` gives something other than a 3-letter weekday name. I'll update my answer to handle this.

Comment: @Jasarien Yes it does (and now so does mine). Though mine is more efficient because it only calls `stringFromDate:` once while yours calls it twice. That's an expensive method call. As in many cases, there is usually more than one way to solve a problem.

Comment: @rmaddy and to Jasarien: Thanks for providing thorough solutions!

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer doesn't really address the asked question. Just like [Hot Licks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/581994/hot-licks) commented, it's possible to set the (standard/short/long/etc) weekday/month symbols on the DateFormatter instance:

```
dateFormatter.shortWeekdaySymbols = dateFormatter.shortWeekdaySymbols.map { $0.localizedUppercase }
dateFormatter.monthSymbols = dateFormatter.monthSymbols.map { $0.localizedCapitalized }
```

If you need to set your formatter's locale to other than the default you should make these calls after doing so.

Comment: this answer deserves a medal

Answer (score 1):

Just get the day on its own, uppercase it, then get the rest of the date and append it. Like so:

```
[dateFormat setFormat:@"EEE"];
NSString *day = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
[dateFormat setFormat:@"MMM. dd"];
NSString *restOfDate = [dateFormat:stringFromDate:today];
NSString *fullDate = [[day uppercaseString] stringByAppendingFormat:@", %@", restOfDate];
```